# XMLRPC one2many, many2one connections SWIFT 4

Tags: swift, odoo, xml-rpc

I'm working with Odoo and trying to make iOS app for it. So i'm facing that problem: How to make one2many, many2one connections in swift 4?

Comment: welcome to Stack over flow. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to connect  Odoo's database and pull information with AlamofireXMLRPC. I pulled out basic fields but there's one2many and many2one connections. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/webservices/odoo.html

Comment: I am really sorry, i am a full time odoo developer but i don't know the interfacing of odoo with the apple devices. Better wait for some one to answer your question :) .

Comment: Thank you so much anyways :)

Comment: No mention.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use xmlrpc in your ios app, you could send raw http request to custom controller routes in order to process the received info on the controllers to properly call odoo backend models orm methods. Like implementing a bridge between you ios app and Odoo into your controllers.

That's what I'm using in an objc app that I'm integrating with Odoo. I will migrate the code base to swift in the future but no need to interact with Odoo using xmlrpc if you could be deliver features using an api rest style more quickly